# Nest could not find PrismaService element (this provider does not exist in the current context)

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I'm trying to get PrismaService on my main.ts, but it's keep crashing. I'm new on this, can anyone help me to solve it?
My prisma.service.ts:

```
import { INestApplication, Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }

  async enableShutdownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
    this.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
      await app.close();
    });
  }
}
```

My main.ts:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { PrismaService } from './prisma.service';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import helmet from 'helmet';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.enableCors({
    allowedHeaders: '*',
    origin: '*',
  });
  app.use(helmet());
  app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());
  app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy());

  const prismaService = app.get(PrismaService);
  await prismaService.enableShutdownHooks(app);

  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true,
      whitelist: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
    }),
  );

  await app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log('runing...'));
}
bootstrap();
```

The error message:

```
Error: Nest could not find PrismaService element (this provider does not exist in the current context)
    at InstanceLinksHost.get (/home/rafittu/wophi/alma/back/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-links-host.js:15:19)
    at NestApplication.find (/home/rafittu/wophi/alma/back/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/abstract-instance-resolver.js:8:60)
    at NestApplication.get (/home/rafittu/wophi/alma/back/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application-context.js:64:20)
    at /home/rafittu/wophi/alma/back/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:133:40
    at Function.run (/home/rafittu/wophi/alma/back/node_modules/@nestjs/core/errors/exceptions-zone.js:10:13)
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (/home/rafittu/wophi/alma/back/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:132:46)
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (/home/rafittu/wophi/alma/back/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:181:54)
    at bootstrap (/home/rafittu/wophi/alma/back/src/main.ts:18:29)
```

When I delete PrismaService from main.ts, server start normaly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `app.get(PrismaService, { strict: false })`. The `strict: false` is to say that `AppModule` doesn't directly provider the provider and to traverse the DI container to find it

Comment: Using strict: false didn't work, same error message

Comment: Do you have a module that has `providers: [PrimsaService]` imported by the `AppModule`?

Comment: Sorted out!!! I have an users module and PrismaService was not imported. As I imported it, server started normaly! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

After setting up the `PrismaService` in `prisma.service.ts` and enabling shutdown hooks in the `main.ts` file, you also need to do the following:

In the `app.module.ts` you need to add `PrismaService` as one of the providers:

```js
...
import { PrismaService } from './prisma/prisma.service';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, PrismaService], // add PrismaService here
})
export class AppModule {}
```